# 'mass update' option in subpannel(in detailview) in sugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have to make 'mass update' option in subpannel(in detailview) just like it is in listview(by default).
I have searched alot from sugar-forum and all possible links but found nothing helpful. Can anyone help how to use default include/massupdate.php or listview etc to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

It should already be there, you just need to add some jQuery call in there to show it ( perhaps via an after_ui_frame logic hook like done in this example ( http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/11/06/showing-the-total-amount-for-a-column-in-a-listview-using-just-logic-hooks-and-jquery/ )

```
$('#massupdate_form').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no default functionality provided by suiteCRM. but it can be achieved in upgrade save way. Here is an example of mass update in the subpanel. This example shows Mass update is implemented in contacts subpanel under accounts detailview.
[massupdate in subpanel](https://github.com/farjad6/SuiteCRM/commit/b5142d70d5491f75b7f4beeaeda3fb8566e021a3)